# How can I take a picture with the depth camera?

Tags: camera

Many phones - such as my Nokia 7.1 - now come with depth cameras and other auxiliary cameras built-in.

For example, my Nokia 7.1 has a front & back facing camera as you might expect, but also has a depth camera listed in the specifications:

[image]

*([link to full specs](https://www.gsmarena.com/nokia_7_1-9354.php))*

With this in mind, I'd like to be able to take a picture with the depth camera on my phone. Unfortunately though, it doesn't show up if I press the switch camera button in the default camera app - that just switches between the front and back facing cameras.

I've also tried a 3rd party camera app ([Open Camera](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.sourceforge.opencamera)) to no effect.

How can I take a picture with the depth camera directly, and save it as a JPEG file?

Comment: Ah, I see @Robert. If nobody else answers, then I'm happy to accept that as the answer to my question for now. It's still a valid answer - even if it's saying that it's not possible....

Answer (score 6):

While the Nokia 7.1 has a 'depth' camera. It is unclear if the 5MP camera has been exposed to developers (doubtful) or is part of the overall camera system for image enhancement (more likely).

On the other hand a phone like [Samsung S10 5G](https://www.gsmarena.com/samsung_galaxy_s10_5g-9588.php) does have a `0.3 MP, TOF 3D, (depth)` sensor accessible to Android app developers.

When referring to depth, its not an hi-res image that a user can look at, but a feature that a camera app developer can take advantage of when the hardware supports it.

For Android developers in the Camera2 API there is [REQUEST_AVAILABLE_CAPABILITIES_DEPTH_OUTPUT](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/CameraMetadata#REQUEST_AVAILABLE_CAPABILITIES_DEPTH_OUTPUT)

Which uses [DEPTH16](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/ImageFormat#DEPTH16) Android Image format.

For the more technically inclined there is a Medium post on [Working with the 3D Camera on the Samsung S10 5G](https://medium.com/swlh/working-with-the-3d-camera-on-the-samsung-s10-5g-4782336783c) where the author goes into how to use the 3D camera data.

A key point from the article is that the resolution of the DOF is much lower than any visible light image.

> The ToF Camera
>
> The front-facing ToF sensor on the Samsung S10 5G is a Sony IMX316. It outputs frames in the DEPTH16 image format with a resolution of **240x180**. It has a 75° field of view, which roughly matches the S10 5G’s front-facing camera’s field of view of 80°.

As you can see in the article, the author is using the depth of field image data for bokeh or background blur as each pixel is a depth value and a confidence level. The author also has to apply a variety of techniques to the DEPTH16 data as it appear to be quite noisy.

Those so inclined can get the author's source code here: https://github.com/plluke/tof